# Conceptual understanding of phase power vs. line power

Tags: power, phase, analysis, line

I am looking at two formulas:

P = √3 x VL x IL x Cos Ф

P = 3 x VPh x IPh x Cos Ф

Now assuming P here refers here to the total power. Could I take VPh and IPh and combine those terms as P (Phase)? Same with VL and IL to P (Line)? Do both P (phase) and P (Line) have the same phase differences between them?

Comment: "assuming P here refers here to the total power" It does, assuming a balanced load. I don't understand the rest of your question. Perhaps you could add the equations you are thinking of to your question? Note that the two power calculations give the same result. (Remember \$V_{Line} = \sqrt3V_{Phase}\$). Instantaneous power is constant through a cycle so there is no phase difference between powers calculated either way.

Comment: So the formulas P = √3 x P(phase) x Cos Ф and P = 3 x P(line) x Cos Ф are what I am thinking of. Could you elaborate a little more on your last sentence? There would be no phase difference between the calculated power for each phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Conceptual understanding of phase power vs. line power

There aren't separate phase power and line powers. There is just one value for power, which you can work out for a balanced load using either of your equations.

> Do both P (phase) and P (Line) have the same phase differences between them?

Instantaneous power (summed across all three phases) is constant through a cycle (a benefit of poly-phase power transmission) so there is no phase difference between powers calculated either way, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_three-phase_electric_power#Constant_power_transfer). Also power is a [scalar](https://byjus.com/questions/is-power-scalar-or-vector/) quantity. There is no phase value to be different.

Comment: I understand. So would this mean that I could calculate line currents in a Wye secondary by dividing the total power by 3 and V(phase)? I(phase1) = P/(3*V(phase1))?

Comment: @Coconut Yes, assuming the load is balanced and resistive. You've left out the \$cos \phi \$ term (= power factor for a linear load) from your question so you've changed from real power (W, kW, etc) in your question to [apparent power](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/power-triangle.html) (VA, kVA, etc) in the above comment. If my answer has solved your original problem please [accept](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.